# Why don't products of Dirac deltas integrate correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

The integral $\int \int \ \delta(x) \delta(y) \ dx dy=1$ evaluates to 0 in Mathematica

```
Integrate[
    DiracDelta[x]*DiracDelta[y],
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    {y, -Infinity, Infinity}
]
```

returns 0 even though

```
Integrate[
    DiracDelta[x],
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}
]
```

correctly returns 1.
What's going on?

**Edit:**
This concerns Version 10.0.0.0 installed on Ubuntu 14.04. The notebook contains no other commands. `Clear[x,y]` does not affect the outcome.

Comment: Works fine in version 10.1:  `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[x]*DiracDelta[y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity,
   Infinity}]` yields $1$.

Comment: `Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*DiracDelta[y],{x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity,Infinity}]` yeilds 1 in 10.0.1 as well.

Comment: Can confirm correct behavior in 8.0.0.0 Win7x64 Enterprise

Comment: Try Clear[x,y] just incase you left them defined from something else? An unlikely silly mistake but you never know.

Comment: ... also works fine in version 9.0.1.0.

Comment: Also okay in 7.0.1 and 5.2. So it seems highly likely, if not user error, that this is a regression that affected only one very specific version. (Perhaps version 6?) Anyway, please note in the question which version you are using.

Comment: I can confirm it on V10.0.0, Mac OSX.  I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Strange. I'll look into upgrading. Thanks all!

Comment: I added back the bugs tag since this appears only in one specific point revision and has been fixed now. If anyone disagrees, please say so.

Answer (score 7):

Summarizing the comments, this was a bug in version 10.0.0. It has been fixed as of version 10.0.1.

```
In[1]:= Integrate[
          DiracDelta[x]*DiracDelta[y], 
         {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
         {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Out[1]= 1
```