# DiracDelta and version 10.0.0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-10

#### Note: This issue seems to affect version 10.0.0 only and is fixed in 10.0.1, 10.0.2, 10.1 and 10.2

---

When evaluating the following two inputs:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1-x] DiracDelta[y-2] Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y,-∞, ∞}]

Integrate[Integrate[DiracDelta[1-x] DiracDelta[y-2] Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -∞, ∞}], {y, -∞, ∞}]
```

I get `0` from the first and (the correct) `Sin[1] Cos[2]` from second.

Can someone explain this to me? I'm using v.10, a friend on v.9 got that the first evaluated the same as the second (as expected).

Comment: I get the correct for both in version 10.1.

Comment: I do have v10.0 tho, perhaps it something they addressed in the update? Naturally I've restarted all kernels etc.

Comment: v10.1 also gives the correct answer when input is written using the multidimensional Dirac delta function form `Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - x, y - 2] Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -Infinity,  Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Comment: Can someone with V10.0.1 or 10.0.2 confirm that the input is working correctly there? Please edit the version in the first part of the question if this is not the case.

Comment: @halirutan - all three forms work correctly with v10.0.1, 10.0.2, and 10.1 on my Mac.

Comment: @BobHanlon OK, then we leave the version information seems to be correct. Thanks for trying.

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/) for another example of `DiracDelta` behaving incorrectly in 10.0.0.

Comment: OK, so it seems to be related to 10.0.0. Indeed strange, and fairly severe. My research involves integrating over many many delta's....

Thanks for the help guys.