# DiracDelta behaves incorrectly on multidimensional integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a reason why this seems to work:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x] F[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> F[0]

But this does not:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x, y] F[x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y,-Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 0

This also gives zero:

```
Integrate[  DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[y] F[x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 0

Comment: Seems to work fine in my case. Have you tried restarting the kernel? Maybe there's a definition of `F` that's altering the result.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  The latter result, at least, is a known bug in v10.0.0;  see [Why don't products of Dirac deltas integrate correctly?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/why-dont-products-of-dirac-deltas-integrate-correctly)

Comment: yes, I'm using mathematica 10, that seems to be the reason

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to avoid upper-case letters (such as your `F`) to start the names of variables and functions.  I suspect your problem was that your `F` had been defined elsewhere during your *Mathematica* session.  Without such a pre-definition, `DiracDelta` works fine in two dimensions:

```
Integrate[
 DiracDelta[x, y] f[x, y], 
  {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
  {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

(*
f[0, 0]
*)

Comment: Why should this make a difference?  I know that it's bad practice to use capitalized variable names because they might conflict with built-in variables, but I don't think there's a built-in function called `F`.  And both `f` and `F` behave properly on my machine.

Comment: in fact it doesn't matter, I still get 0 on Mathematica 10

Comment: Try closing and re-opening *Mathematica*.  You shouldn't be getting such an error on a simple problem.